# WHM terminal help - SWAP file delete

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpanel, whm

I am just trying to setup a WHM/cPanel on DigitalOcean for education purpose.

I found this link to secure WHM - https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/cpanel-whm-server-security/

Will running this command

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I am getting below error (I tried the command before but I disconnected without saving)

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/ssh/.sshd_config.swp"
      owned by: root   dated: Tue Oct 16 13:18:49 2018
     file name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      modified: YES
     user name: root   host name: host.enrich.press
    process ID: 13934
While opening file "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
         dated: Tue Oct 16 14:45:07 2018
  NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/ssh/.sshd_config.swp"
to avoid this message.
"/etc/ssh/sshd_config" 140L, 3944C
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I deal with this?

Comment: You could do `diff /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/.sshd_config.swp` to see the differences (if any) in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably exited vim incorrectly (stopped the job and put it in background) or you have another terminal also editing the very same file. Simply put, vim creates swap file when you are editing file in which it writes the changes and it removes the file once you exit vim, i.e. stop the process. So you have a few options:

1. Close the other instance of vim and open the file again
2. If you have stopped vim with ctrl+z for example, execute `jobs` then you will get a list with numbers in front of the names of the things running, once knowing the number of the job, just do `fg 1` or whatever the number is
3. (Not a good one, but sometimes is necessary) Delete the .swp file and open the file again

Hope this helps!